# Do I have to store or calculate statistics whenever I need them?

Tags: sql, database, design-patterns, statistics

I am creating an application and I will need statistics from the data I will have in my SQL database.

For example, I have a table "animals", with a column "type" that can be equal to "dog" or "cat". I need to calculate statistics of the type "number of animals", which will therefore be equal to the number of entities in my table "animals", or "percentage of cat", which will therefore be equal to the number of cat/ number of animals * 100.

This example was simplified to the maximum, but in my application, it will be more complex calculations, and in greater numbers.

For my statistics, do I have to create another "statistics" table, and update it every time I modify my "animals" table, or do I calculate these statistics every time I have a request on my API? What are the best practices?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360738

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to do the calculation when you need it.  That way, you are ensured that the results are always aligned with the data.

Sometimes, your data grows large.  Your system gets really busy.  Your need for a fast response time is paramount.  In those cases, you think about how to make the code more efficient.  That is when you start to think about a separate statistics table.

If you did have such a table, you would not keep the ratio in the table -- at least not solely.  Instead, you would have counters for "dogs" and "cats".  Then you would use triggers for `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s to keep those values up-to-date.  Of course, the triggers add overhead.

You may also have a situation where the statistics are only needed periodically (such as once per day).  In this scenario, you can run a batch job to create a statistics table -- running the batch during more quiescent periods for the database.  The data is out-of-date, but this can meet performance expectations more simply than maintaining a `statistics` table in real-time.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll take a look for those triggers, but just compute when I need them for the moment :)