# SQL Inner Join With Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I've got 2 tables - **dishes** and **ingredients**:

in **Dishes,** I've got a list of pizza dishes, ordered as such:
[image: Dishes Table]

In **Ingredients,** I've got a list of all the different ingredients for all the dishes, ordered as such:[image: Ingredients Table]

I want to be able to **list all the names of all the ingredients of each dish alongside each dish's name**.

I've written this query that does not replace the ingredient ids with names as it should, instead opting to return an empty set - please explain what it that I'm doing wrong:

```
    SELECT dishes.name, ingredients.name, ingredients.id
FROM dishes
INNER JOIN ingredients
ON dishes.ingredient_1=ingredients.id,dishes.ingredient_2=ingredients.id,dishes.ingredient_3=ingredients.id,dishes.ingredient_4=ingredients.id,dishes.ingredient_5=ingredients.id,dishes.ingredient_6=ingredients.id, dishes.ingredient_7=ingredients.id,dishes.ingredient_8=ingredients.id;
```

It would be great if you could refer to:

1. *The logic of the DB structuring* - am I doing it correctly?
2. *The logic behind the SQL query* - if the DB is built in the right fashion, then why upon executing the query I get the empty set?
3. If you've encountered such a problem before - one that *requires a single-to-many relationship* - how did you solved it in a way different than this, using PHP & MySQL?

***Disregard The Text In Hebrew - Treat It As Your Own Language.***

Comment: Is hard to disregard. But you may consider prepare an [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6). is easy work with text than pictures

Comment: Your query is illogical. You're selecting rows with pizzas made of 8 *identical* ingredients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The logic of the DB structuring - am I doing it correctly?**

- This is denormalized data. To normalize it, you would restructure your database into three tables:

  - `Pizza`
  - `PizzaIngredients`
  - `Ingredients`

`Pizza` would have `ID`, `name`, and `type` where `ID` is the primary key.

`PizzaIngredients` would have `PizzaId` and `IngredientId` (this is a many-many table where the primary key is a composite key of `PizzaId` and `IngredientID`)

`Ingredients` has `ID` and `name` where `ID` is the primary key.

**2. List all the names of all the ingredients of each dish alongside each dish's name. Something like this in `MySQL` (untested):**

```
SELECT p.ID, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(i.name) AS ingredients
FROM pizza p
INNER JOIN pizzaingredients pi ON p.ID = pi.PizzaID
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON pi.IngredientID = i.ID
GROUP BY p.id
```

**3. If you've encountered such a problem before - one that requires a single-to-many relationship - how did you solved it in a way different than this, using PHP & MySQL?**

- Using a many-many relationship, since that what your example truly is. You have many pizzas which can have many ingredients. And many ingredients belong to many different pizzas.

Comment: What's with the `p.` ? I don't get what it stands for.

Comment: It is a table alias, you can look it up.

Comment: So, when you say `pizza p` you're setting the `p` for `pizza`? Because if not, you're not declaring it anywhere.

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub That is exact what he does. Also name `pizzaingredients pi` that way name are shorter and easy to read

Comment: Okay - this works. Problem is, it only shows me **One** pizza when I want to see all of them. Why is that?

Comment: @EricHotinger - Alsom is there way to break the Concatenation into seperate members of the array? Have one of them as a name, and the others as ingredients?

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub - you have a lot of different questions. Post new questions to SO with the specifics, don't try to answer 10 questions in one post.

Comment: @EricHotinger - You are correct indeed. New question if you've got some time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943437/break-concatenation-into-seperate-entities-in-php

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that a better Database Structure would have a **Dishes_Ingredients_Rel** table, rather than having a bunch of columns for Ingredients.

```
DISHES_INGREDIENTS_REL
DishesID
IngredientID
```

Then, you could just do a much simpler JOIN.

```
SELECT Ingredients.Name
FROM Dishes_Ingredients_Rel
    INNER JOIN Ingredients
        ON Dishes_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
WHERE Dishes_Ingredients_Rel.DishesID = @DishesID
```

Comment: Shit this seems so much simpler. God bless SO. Let me build one real quick. @John Pasquet - Back in a sec with the tick mark.

Comment: I think you need include `DISHES` in the join too In case you want all Dishes instead of ony one

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I completely agree, if he wants all ingredients for all dishes.  He did say "each" instead of "all", so perhaps his logic will be contained in a foreach statement.  If not, your suggestion is what he'll need.

Comment: @JohnPasquet - if a pizza has more than 1 ingredient, how do I include it in the rel table? Just add a lot of rows?

Comment: Yes.  Just add more rows.  The alternative is to have as many columns as you have ingredients.  Anytime you add a new ingredient, you would have to add another column.  That gets old fast.

Comment: That's not an alternative

Comment: @Strawberry - care to elaborate? What's wrong with John Pasquet's alternative besides of the fact that it's bad DB design practice?

Comment: Why does there have to be a 'besides'? There's absolutely no requirement to use an RDBMS for these kinds of problems, but if you are going to use one then it seems sensible to take on board all that that entails - e.g. normalisation (to 3NF).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an empty result is because you are setting a join condition that never gets satisfied. During the INNER join execution the database engine compares each record of the first table with each record of the second one trying to find a match where the id of the ingredient table record being evaluated is equal to ingredient1 AND ingredient2 AND so on. It would return some result if you create a record in the first table with the same ingredient in all 8 columns (testing purposes only).

Regarding the database structure, you choose a denormalized one creating 8 columns for each ingredient. There are a lot of considerations possible on this data structure (performance, maintainability, or just think if you are asked to insert a dish with 9 ingredients for example) and I would personally go for a normalized data structure instead.

But if you want to keep this, you should write something like:

```
SELECT dishes.name, ingredients1.name, ingredients1.id, ingredients2.name, ingredients2.id, ...
FROM dishes
LEFT JOIN ingredients AS ingredients1 ON dishes.ingredient_1=ingredients1.id
LEFT JOIN ingredients AS ingredients2 ON dishes.ingredient_2=ingredients2.id
LEFT JOIN ingredients AS ingredients3 ON dishes.ingredient_3=ingredients3.id
...
```

The LEFT join is required to get a result for unmatched ingredients (0 value when no ingredient is set reading your example)

Comment: I actually don't mind changing it. Can you explain *de-* vs normalised DB Structures?

Comment: Normalized data structures best suit On-Line Transactional Processing (OLTP) denormalized On-Line Analytical Processing (OLAP). The purpose of normalization is to avoid (or reduce) data redundancy. It's a wide topic. 

Have a look here: http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html
And to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293425/in-terms-of-databases-is-normalize-for-correctness-denormalize-for-performanc