# Should derived values be persisted?

Tags: java

I am bit confused should we store derived values in DB or not ? For example :- If want to do some calculation on employee salary and display it on UI.

There are two approaches :-

**Approach 1:-** Either i calculate the derived value each time we need to display on UI.

**Approach 2:-** Persists the derived value in separate column when persisting the salary itself.

Approach 2 is good from performance point of view but bad from maintainability point of view . Its bad from maintainability point as i have to maintain extra column.
Similarly for approach 1 is good from maintainability point of view but bad from performance point of view and also extra work each time i need to derive the value.

Which approach is better ?  Per mine understanding if calculation is complex and used at multiple places we should approach 2 otherwise 1. Is that right ?

Comment: What about just storing it in a var?

Comment: How much performance do you really expect to burn when calculating the derived value? It's 2017 and computers are fast as well as furious.

Comment: (i) it's hard to guess about performance => measure (correctly) and you may be surprised (ii) you could create a view in your DB without creating a new column. (iii) if the formula changes for whatever reason, do you prefer to touch your database schema or change your application code?

Comment: Unless you are calculating the meaning of life, the universe and everything else you should use the first approach

Comment: try the simplest approach first.  then optimise it if you have to.  don't try to guess at performance issues: you'll go insane!

Comment: @Kayaman I understand that performance is not a big concern. But I am comparing two approaches. What's wrong in approach 2?

Comment: I am not sure why this question is put on hold based on opinion. This is the real design problem I face in almost every project. I think its not based on opinion and certainly be answered in black and white something like @Andreas answered. Basically folks can tell in certain scenario approach 1 is good and certain scenarios approach 2 is good .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally not store derived values, unless:

1. It's complicated/expensive to calculate (e.g. requiring values from many other records)
2. You need an index on the value for fast lookup.

Storing derived data is called *denormalizing*. For further research, you should read articles about why to [normalize vs denormalize](https://www.google.com/search?q=normalize+vs+denormalize) data.

See also this question: [In terms of databases, is “Normalize for correctness, denormalize for performance” a right mantra?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/293425/5221149)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. But what's the wrong with approach 2?

Comment: would appreciate if you can provide your inputs on Approach 2 ?

Comment: @emilly I already did, by updating the answer last time you asked about approach 2, adding links to articles discussing pros and cons of denormalizing a database.