# Is there a limit to how long a SQL query can be in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum size for a SQL Server Query? IN clause? Is there a Better Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach)

I Googled for a while and can't find whether there's some hard limit on how huge query strings can be in SQL Server. I mean what if I build a 100 million character query - will it run or will the server just drop it as too long?

Is there a limit to how long SQL query can be (in terms of characters or tokens or whatever like that) in SQL Server?

Comment: Looks like the answer may be in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869753/maximum-size-for-a-sql-server-query-in-clause-is-there-a-better-approach).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I never encountered a problem of SQL query being too long in terms of number of characters, but there is a **maximum number of tables** a query can reference (256) and I hit this limitation a few times.

[Have you ever encountered a query that SQL Server could not execute because it referenced too many tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432/95)

**UPDATE**
In recent versions of SQL Server, the number of tables per `SELECT` statement is **limited only by available resources**.

Comment: The downvote here feels a little harsh to me. Not the exact answer required, but certainly related.

Comment: How long (an estimation will be helpful too) was the longest query you produced?

Comment: @sharptooth: About 250 KB, but it was a view referencing other views. I'm not 100% sure about that, but I read somewhere that, when executing such queries, SQL Server replaces the referenced views with actual SELECT statements they contain, so the size of original query increases.

Comment: View substitution doesn't happen at a source code / textual level. It stores algebrized trees for the views then chucks them in later in the process.

Comment: @sharptooth: I remembered wrong - it's 72 KB (not 250 KB).

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz How did you reference that many tables?

Comment: It was a reporting system built directly on top of an OLTP database (very bad practice, I know). It was normalized, so getting a dataset for a report required tens of joins. As soon as a report touched a few different business processes, the number of joins grew two- or threefold.